# Standard deviation of an autocorrelated time series

Tags: time-series, correlation, standard-deviation, autocorrelation, robust

Given a time series of log returns $R_t$ with significant autocorrelation up to $k$ lags, what is the formula for the standard deviation of $R_t$ that accounts for this autocorrelation?

I've seen the following formula which appears related to NeweyWest:

$ \sigma_{adj} = \sigma \sqrt{\frac{1 + 2\sum_{i=1}^k \rho_i}{n}} $

and the following, the source of which im unsure:

$ \sigma_{adj} = \sigma \sqrt{\frac{1+\rho_1^2}{1-\rho_1^2}} $

The latter appears suboptimal by accounting only for 1 lag. My question remains, what is the correct way to account for this bias in the calculation of $\sigma$?